# I had studied at St Mary's School. Is this sentence grammatically right or wrong?

Tags: grammar

I had studied at St Mary's School. 
Is this sentence grammatically right or wrong?

Comment: Needs more context. If you are trying to use 'had' the way I think, then that ain't normal, but in other cases it might be fine.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am trying to tell about my early education.

Comment: So give us one sentence from either side of this.